# How to use rspec-expectations outside cucumber step-definitions

Tags: ruby, rspec, cucumber, watir, watir-webdriver

I'm using watir-cucumber for test automation. I wrote following method in a separate `.rb`, this method is not in step definitions.

```
 def has_logged_in?
   $browser.text.should include("t788")
 end
```

When I call this method from step definition this error comes,

```
 wrong argument type String (expected Module) (TypeError)
```

the same code works fine in step definitions. I searched around and found out that `include` method is used to include module but that is `ruby-include` method and `should include` comes under `rspec\expectations`. So how do I call `should include` method outside step definition like above.
I'm using watir-cucumber on linux

Comment: Where and why you wrote that method?

Comment: you could do `text.should =~ /t788/` just as well

Comment: @IsmaelAbreu I wanted to test if user has logged in so instead of writing it for every step I would like to call this function and then it will decide step is passed or failed. This is to avoid repetation in code

Answer (score 5):

The `include` method that you want is in the [`RSpec::Matchers`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-expectations/RSpec/Matchers#include-instance_method) module.

If your `has_logged_in?` method is in a class (not part of main), you can include the RSpec::Matchers module in your class. This would give you access to the `include` method.

So your class would look like:

```
class YourClass
    include RSpec::Matchers

    def has_logged_in?
        $browser.text.should include("t788")
    end
end
```

Note: I have not had to do this before, but from a quick check, it does work as long as the RSpec::Matchers are included in a class rather than the main. Including it in the main does not appear to do anything (ie include continues to call the standard include module method). I did not explore to see if if there are any negative side effects of doing this.

Comment: @UdaySwami is it the same exception you saw before? Can you share your entire .rb file?

Answer (score 0):

In your gem file:

```
gem 'rspec', "1.3.2", :require => "spec/expectations"
```

Or in your env.rb for RSpec 1.X.X:

```
require 'spec/expectations'
```

Or in your env.rb for RSpec 2.X:

```
require 'rspec/expectations'
```